# yahoo messages with php

Tags: php, api, yahoo

Is there an yahoo Api that can help you send yahoo instant messages with PHP ?
I googled for it but I found forums with threads from like 3,4 years ago... I found some classes that didnt work and so on. Can someone help me?

Comment: There are several alternatives.  For starters, have you looked [here: developer.yahoo.com/messenger/guide](http://developer.yahoo.com/messenger/guide/index.html)?

Comment: ys, but I really didnt find anything specific to my need.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes there is a [messenger-sdk-php](https://github.com/yahoo/messenger-sdk-php).

you need to create a new instance of the class:

```
$engine = new JYMEngine(CONSUMER_KEY, SECRET_KEY, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
```

signon using a yahoo account:

```
$engine->fetch_request_token();
$engine->fetch_access_token();
$engine->signon('Status message');
```

then you can send messages :

```
$engine->send_message('yahooID', $message);
```

sample client provided with the code is a good place to start. it accepts any friend requests and accepts orders like help(show available commands),news(show news titles from yahoo),...

Comment: to get the consumerkey and secret key , sign in to yahoo and visit [this page](https://developer.apps.yahoo.com/projects) then create a standard WebBased project. also in Access Scopes check "This app requires access to private user data." and check Full Access under Yahoo! Messenger.